# All values discarded from spark dataframe while filtering blank values using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some spark code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
    df=spark.read.parquet("D:\\source\\202204121920-seller_central_opportunity_explorer_category.parquet")
```

[image]

I have `parent_ids` field which is blank. I need only the records whose `parent_ids` are `Blank`. I searched into the SO and I found these answers:

```
df1=df.where(df["parent_ids"].isNull())
df1.toPandas()

df1=df.filter("parent_ids is NULL")
df1.toPandas()

df.filter(f.isnull("parent_ids")).show()
df.where(f.isnull(f.col("parent_ids"))).show()
```

Since there is clearly that parent_ids are `Null`, when I try to look the result I am getting `0 record counts.`
[image]
Why is my result showing `zero counts` thoughthere are `parent_ids` which are blank? Any option I tired didnt worked.

Comment: What is the datatype of `parent_ids`?

Comment: note - nulls would print as `null` in a spark dataframe. blanks and whitespaces would look like the one in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data is not null, it is empty :

```py
df.where("parent_ids = ''").show()
```